# python 3 -- query file and recurse to next file

Tags: python-3.x, exif

New to Python 3 and programming in general. I'm trying to write a script which will recurse through over 50 folders containing more than 30,000 files, pull the EXIF data from the file and then continue on to every file thereafter till it reaches the end. As it stands right now, my script will only check the very first file and I then get a "No such file or directory" on the second file. Here's what I've got so far.

```
 import os
    import exifread

    for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk("C:\\Users\\Ken\\Desktop\\test\\temp"):
         for f in filenames:
            myInfo = open(f, 'rb')
            tags = exifread.process_file(myInfo)
            print(tags)
```

I've Googled till I can't see straight, read through books, etc, but I'm just not getting it. If I still had hair, I'd have torn it out by now. I've probably worked at it too long and I'm just confusing myself, but I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!
Ken

Comment: I've changed it slightly from the above. I added a line to close myInfo. Still not figuring out what I'm doing wrong otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You should use,

```
myInfo = open(os.path.join(root, f), 'rb')
```

istead. Since `f` is a filename relative to the root directory, simply calling `open(f, 'rb')` will fail.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give that a shot and see how it goes.